# Updating values in a map from another map

Tags: java, java-8

I have a map `AdmissionData< String, AdmissionData >` which maps a student ID to his admission details.

```
AdmissionData {  String joinDate; String sequenceID; String standard }
```

From this map,I need to update details of every student on a master map `StudentData<String , StudentData >` for every student.

```
StudentData {............ ;String joinDate; String sequenceID; String standard }
```

What is the best way to achieve this efficiently?

Comment: What have you tried, and in what way(s) is it insufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate `AdmissionData` map using `forEach` and the. update `StudentData` map using [computeIfPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```
admissionData.forEach((key,value) -> {
   studentData.computeIfPresent(key,(existingKey,existingValue) -> /*logic */);

});
```

Comment: I tried to use studentData.computeIfPresent(key,(k,v) -> {v.setJoinDate(value.getJoinDate()); v.setSequenceId(value.getSequenceId());}).However,it gives a compile error - the type HashMap<String,StudentData> is not applicable for the arguments (String, (<no type> k, <no type> v) -> {}

Answer (score 0):

#### Your question as I understood

- you have a map *admissionMap* with entries: `String` (student-id) mapped to `AdmissionData` object
- you have another map *masterMap* with entries: `String` (student-id) mapped to `StudentData` object
- you want to update the objects on map *masterMap* (the target) with some properties of correlated (by student-id) objects from map *admissionMap* (the source)

How to do this?

#### Given

These maps with some values, where the keys are correlated (*student-id*) and can match.

```java
Map<String, AdmissionData> admissionMap;
Map<String, StudentData> masterMap;
```

The `AdmissionData` class has some properties

```java
public class AdmissionData {
    String joinDate;
    String sequenceID;
    String standard

    // getter and setter omitted
}
```

Some of those are also in the class `StudentData`:

```java
public class StudentData {
    // other properties

    // properties with same name and contents as in class AdmissionData
    String joinDate;
    String sequenceID;
    String standard

    // getter and setter omitted
}
```

#### The Mapping

Could be done using Java 8 streaming with `forEach` and conditional map-update either using `computeIfPresent` or the traditional way:

```java
admissionData.forEach((key,value) -> {
   // update only if sudent-id is present as key
   if (studentData.containsKey(key)) {
       StudentData existingStudent = studentData.get(key);
       // update the fields: set with values from AdmissionData 
       existingStudent.setJoinDate(value.getJoinDate());
       existingStudent.setSequenceID(value.getSequenceID());
       existingStudent.setStandard(value.getStandard());
   }
});
```

The actual mapping (copying of values) is done with above statement like `existingStudent.setX(value.getX());` where `value` is the source entry of type `AdmissionData` which will have the same property named `X` (also same type!).

Comment: BTW: `Data` is a very ambiguous and meaningless noun for naming variables, fields, classes, methods. In most cases it will confuse and harms readability, thus considered bad-practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using the updateAll() function:

```
void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> sourceMap = {'text': 'init text', 'value': 1};
  Map<String, dynamic> modifiedMap = {'text': 'modified text', 'value': 10};
  
  print(sourceMap); // {text: init text, value: 1}
  
  sourceMap.updateAll((key, value) => modifiedMap[key]);
  
  print(sourceMap); // {text: modified text, value: 10}
}
```